# add a pattern on the outside of a circle (spheric mirror)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, pst-optic

I want to make some basic drawings of optics. I've consulted pst-optics, but this very nice package was to complicated for the drawings that I need.

My question is: I want to add a pattern on the outside of the circle (the same is the plane mirror). In fact I also need the pattern on the inside (couple of mm), but I think when I have the first, the second will be similar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 60] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=5,xmin=0,xmax=10]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{4/1/B, 2/1/C, 6/1/D, 6/0.8/F}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](135:4){A};
\draw (A)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (B);
\tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
\draw [fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none] (C) rectangle (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=8,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{11/4/O, 1/4/S, 6/4/F}
\tkzDefCircle[radius](O,S)
\tkzDrawCircle(O,S)
\tkzDrawPoints(O,S,F)
\tkzLabelPoints(O,S,F)
\draw [->, very thick] (11,4) -- (11,6);
\draw [thick] (0,4) -- (18,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer; now the radius is calculated automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 60] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=5,xmin=0,xmax=10]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{4/1/B, 2/1/C, 6/1/D, 6/0.8/F}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](135:4){A};
\draw (A)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (B);
\tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
\draw [fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none] (C) rectangle (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=8,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{11/4/O, 1/4/S, 6/4/F, 8/4/V}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[V](90:2){VV};
\tkzDefCircle[radius](O,S)
\tkzGetLength{rOSpt}
\tkzpttocm(\rOSpt){rOScm}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,S)
\tkzDrawPoints(O,S,F)
\tkzLabelPoints(O,S,F)
\draw [->, thick] (V) -- (VV);
\tkzDrawLines[add= 0.1 and 0.2](O,S);
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (S) arc[start angle=180,end angle=140,radius=\rOScm cm] --
  ++(-10pt,0pt) arc[start angle=140,end angle=220,radius=\rOScm cm] -- 
  ++(10pt,0pt) arc[start angle=220,end angle=180,radius=\rOScm cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And another option using an arc instead of a full clipped circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 60] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=5,xmin=0,xmax=10]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{4/1/B, 2/1/C, 6/1/D, 6/0.8/F}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](135:4){A};
\draw (A)-- node[sloped] {\midarrow} (B);
\tkzDrawSegment[very thick](C,D);
\draw [fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none] (C) rectangle (F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\StartAngle{150}
\def\EndAngle{210}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=8,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid

\tkzDefPoints{11/4/O, 1/4/S, 6/4/F, 8/4/V}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[V](90:2){VV};
\tkzDefCircle[radius](O,S)
\tkzGetLength{rOSpt}
\tkzpttocm(\rOSpt){rOScm}

% the two ends of the arc M is the upper end and N is the lower end
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(11,4)}](\StartAngle:\rOScm){M}
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(11,4)}](\EndAngle:\rOScm){N}
\tkzDrawArc(O,M)(N)
%\tkzDrawCircle(O,S)
\tkzDrawPoints(O,S,F)
\tkzLabelPoints(O,S,F)
\draw [->, thick] (V) -- (VV);
\tkzDrawLines[add= 0.1 and 0.2](O,S);
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
  (M)  --
  ++(-10pt,0pt) arc[start angle=\StartAngle,end angle=\EndAngle,radius=\rOScm cm] -- 
  ++(10pt,0pt) arc[start angle=\EndAngle,end angle=\StartAngle,radius=\rOScm cm] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: thanks for the added automation!

Comment: @Arne You're welcome. In fact, I improved it a little more in my newly updated answer by using native `tkz-euclide` tools, so ne no need for the calc library anymore.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: I've changed the definition of the arrow and the line OS. I should have done it in my question. :-)

Comment: @Arne Please be careful with your edits; you had  `\tkzDrawLines[add= 0.1 and 0.2](O,M);` and this triggered an error (M was not defined); it should have been  `\tkzDrawLines[add= 0.1 and 0.2](O,S);`. I fixed it already in my code.

Comment: Sorry, I took the wrong start with my drawing, I had to change it in my lessons to O-F-M instead of my example S-F-O. Didn't change it in the adaption of your answer. :-(

Comment: @Arne No problem. I added another option using an arc and with bettwe coding that might be of interest for you.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: Thanks but I don't think tikz knows the intersection between a line and arc, I think I will have to use the circle for this. So I can create an intersection of the light-beam with the mirror.

Comment: @Arne Ah, I see. In that case, then yes, perhaps it's better to use the circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29567/discussion-between-arne-and-gonzalo-medina).

Comment: I've tried to understand the logic of the arc code, but I didn't managed to make the pattern on the inside of the circle. Now I've changed every thing for the convex mirror, but it didn't work out. Also changed for the convex mirror \tkzDefPoints{1/4/M, 9/4/O, 15/4/V} 
\tkzDefMidPoint(M,O) \tkzGetPoint{F}