# Geometrical optics

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

It is possible to make this ray tracing diagram in a simpler way, with less code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=-3,ymax=5.5,xmin=-7,xmax=7]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{5/0/C', -5/0/C, -1.25/0/O, -2.5/0/F,  0/0/S}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](90:1.5){VV};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[O](-90:1.5){W};
\tkzDefCircle[radius](C,S)
\tkzGetLength{rCSpt}
\tkzpttocm(\rCSpt){rCScm}
\tkzDrawArc[angles, color=black](C,S)(320,40)
\tkzDrawPoints(C, O,S,F)
\tkzLabelPoints(C, O, S,F)
\tkzDrawLines[add= 0.2 and 0.1](C,S S,C');
\fill[pattern=north east lines]
(S) arc[start angle=180,end angle=220,radius=-\rCScm cm] --
++(10pt,0pt) arc[start angle=220,end angle=140,radius=-\rCScm cm] --
++(-10pt,0pt) arc[start angle=140,end angle=180,radius=-\rCScm cm];
\tkzDefPointBy[translation= from O to S](VV)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefPointBy[translation= from O to S](W)
\tkzGetPoint{W'}
\tkzInterLC(VV,D)(C,S) \tkzGetPoints{G}{E}
\tkzDrawLines[-latex, thick,color=red, add= 0 and 2](E,F)
\tkzInterLL(O,VV)(E,F)
\tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzInterLC(VV,C)(C,S) \tkzGetPoints{H}{J}
\tkzDrawSegments[-latex, thick,color=red](VV,H)
\tkzInterLL(VV,C)(D,F)
\tkzGetPoint{N}
\tkzInterLL(H,N)(E,F)
\tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[M](90:3){P}
\tkzInterLL(C,S)(M,P)
\tkzGetPoint{Q}
\tkzDrawSegments[-latex, thick,color=red](VV,E VV,J)
\tkzDrawSegments[-latex, very thick](Q,M O,VV)
\tkzDrawLines[-latex, dashed,color=red, add= 0 and 0.5](E,M H,N)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code is based on what Gonzalo Medina proposed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269646/127162).

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain about the missing `begin{document}` ?

Comment: Did you try `ctan optics` on google? // Did you check Link and Related in the rightmost column of this web-page?

Comment: What is your goal? If the goal is to make the shortest possible code, then you should ask at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: `tkz-euclide` is intended to create Euclidean geometry figures, here you can use `TikZ` or `tikz optics`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't know is this is more simple, or if it has less code. It's more like another approach, with Ti*k*Z (no so different for the one you posted, in fact). As Alain Matthes said in the comments, probably the best solution is `tikz-opctics` because it's designed for this kind of drawing but I had never used it myself.

For the Ti*k*Z solution we want to use the `calc` library for the position of some points and, above all, `intersections` library. This way we can draw the picture as we'd do it by hand.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\tikzset{ray/.style={red,-latex},object/.style={thick,blue,-latex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% dimensions
\def\r {4}  % mirror radius
\def\a{30}  % mirror angle
\def\ox{3}  % object position
\def\oy{1}  % object height
% known coordinates
\coordinate (C)  at (0,0);
\coordinate (F)  at (0.5*\r,0);
\coordinate (O)  at (\ox,0);
\coordinate (S)  at (\r,0);
\coordinate (C1) at (\ox,\oy);
% intersections
\draw[thick,name path=horizontal] (C) + (-1,0) --++ (7,0);
\path[name path=C ray]            (C) -- ($(C1)!-3cm!(C)$);
\path[name path=horizontal ray]   (C1) --++ (4,0);
\path[name path=mirror]           (\a:\r) arc (\a:-\a:\r);
\path[name intersections={of=C ray and mirror,by={C2}}];
\path[name intersections={of=horizontal ray and mirror,by={F1}}];
\path[name path=F ray]            (F) -- ($(F1)!-2cm!(F)$);
\path[name intersections={of=C ray and F ray,by={C3}}];
\path[name path=image]            (C3) --++ (0,-3);
\path[name intersections={of=image and horizontal,by={I}}];
% rays
\draw[ray,densely dashed] (C2) -- ($(C3)!-1cm!(C)$);
\draw[ray,densely dashed] (F1) -- ($(C3)!-1cm!(F1)$);
\draw[ray,shorten <=-1cm] (C)  -- (C2);
\draw[ray,shorten >=-3cm] (C1) -- (F1) -- (F);
% mirror, object, image
\fill[gray,opacity=0.2]   (C)  +  (\a:\r) arc (\a:-\a:\r) --++ (0.25,0) arc (-\a:\a:\r) -- cycle;
\draw                     (C)  +  (\a:\r) arc (\a:-\a:\r);
\draw[object]             (O)  -- (C1);
\draw[object,dashed]      (I)  -- (C3);
% labels
\foreach\i in {C,O,F,I}
  \fill (\i) circle (1pt) node [below]      {$\i$};
  \fill (S)  circle (1pt) node [below left] {$S$};
% uncomment the following to see the coordinates
%\foreach\i in {C1,C2,C3,F1} \node[circle,cyan,fill=white,inner sep=0] at (\i) {\tiny$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]