# Drawing curved reflecting mirrors in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, optical

I want to draw the following diagram involving two reflecting mirrors. I don't know how to draw them in Tikz. I will be glad if someone can help me drawing this.[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269642/add-a-pattern-on-the-outside-of-a-circle-spheric-mirror

Comment: Thank You for helping. I was exactly looking for this.